# Delete all highscores from a certain country

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, delete

I have two tables:

```
tbl_players
tbl_highscores
```

I need to delete all highscores that are registered from a certain country. My problem is that the language are set per player, rather than by highscore. I can gather the information with `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT scorePoints, playerAlias, playerEmail, playerCountry
    FROM tbl_highscores JOIN tbl_players ON tbl_highscores.playerId = tbl_players.playerId 
    WHERE playerCountry = 'lt'
```

But how do I delete all highscores that are saved by a user from a certain language?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, if you already know which player's data to delete, why does it matter the country? Or you meant to say: "how do I delete all highscores that are saved by ALL USERS from a certain language"?

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE B.* FROM
(
    SELECT playerId FROM tbl_players 
    WHERE playerCountry = 'lt'
) A INNER JOIN tbl_highscores B
USING (playerId);
```

Make sure you have this index

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_players ADD INDEX CountryIDIndex (playerCountry,playerId);
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete the records in tbl_highscores for *all* players with a specific playerCountry:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_highscores
WHERE playerId IN (
    SELECT playerId 
    FROM tbl_players
    WHERE playerCountry = 'lt')
```

Comment: That will be very slow in MySQL.  IN (SELECT) is evaluated outside->in, so for every row in tbl_highscores, the subselect will be re-executed.